# Accessing bluetooth hardware at webserver

Tags: bluetooth

Assume you have a webserver with a web-application running and a bluetooth module installed on the webserver.

Would it be possible to open a bluetooth connection from the webserver bluetooth module to another bluetooth device when a user triggers an action in the web-application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, this is possible - since you don't state whether your runtime environment is Java or .NET:

For .NET/C# see
http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/Transferring-Files-and-Monitoring-Bluetooth-Ports
http://32feet.codeplex.com/

For Java see
http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/bluetooth2/
http://sourceforge.net/projects/bluecove/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So there are no security constrains that prevent the web application to access the bluetooth module?

Comment: that depends on the configuration of your webserver... the bluetooth module could be disable and/or the account your web application is running could be forbidden to access that module... but this is more a question of your runtime environment than anything else